# $.ajax in vb.net not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have an error and I cannot see why it occurs when I'm doing a basic AJAX call in `aspx`.

The code:

```js
function DownloadClick() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pagetest.aspx/DownloadFolder",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    }); 
}
```

```vb
Partial Class pagetest

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function DownloadFolder() As String

        Return "OK it hit the serverside"

    End Function

End Class
```

I am sure it is basic error but not having done it this way for a long time, I am guessing (hoping) it's a silly mistake.

Comment: Need more info I'm afraid. Do you see anything in the browser console? Is the `DownloadFolder` method being called at all?

Comment: What error do you have? Does calling "pagetest.aspx/DownloadFolder" in the browser works?

Comment: It does seem to preform an event i.e. the downloadfolder method is called with code 200. however it doesn't get to the file (the breakpoint isnt hit)

Comment: "it doesn't get to the file" - that makes no sense, what file are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, to the aspx.vb file - the method (DownloadFolder) it is trying to call

Comment: I thought I may need to do this using an asmx file? I dont know.

Comment: To the editor @RaisingAgent, please be more careful with your edits. You caused the VB code to not be formatted as code. I've corrected it, and given you credit for the other changes you made, but if you don't know VB, I would suggest not editing questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url: "pagetest.aspx/DownloadFolder", is not right.

Regards

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.